# How do I get the current height and width of a background image

Tags: css, svg, styled-components, image-scaling, react-tsx

The problem that I'm facing is that the image height is not scaling with the width as I want it to. I have tried `background-size: cover` and `background-size: contain`  as well as using `object-fit`. None of those options is giving me what I intend: **having the height of the conteiner depend on the width of the container.**

I figured that the height percentage of the current width should be `height:calc(currentHeight/currentWidth*100)`. Now I thought of using `useRef` from react to get the current values everytime the window size changes with an onLoad fuction but I don't know **how to target the svg that is being loaded in my CSS**. All examples that I have encountered are using the `img` tag.

Background image CSS:

```
const Background = styled.section`
  border: solid 1px red;
  background: url(${Donationsvg}) no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
`;
```

Page content structure:

```
<Background>
        <Grid>
  
           <Card>
              <Button>
                <h4>title</h4>
              </Button>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisic.</p>
            </Card>

            <Card>
              <Button>
                <h4>title</h4>
              </Button>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisic.</p>
            </Card>

            <Card>
              <Button>
                <h4>title</h4>
              </Button>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisic.</p>
            </Card>
          
<Background>
```

Comment: change height to `height:auto` and that will keep its aspect ratio to the width

Comment: Using `height:auto` makes the image cut with `background-size:cover` and leaving white spaces on the sides with `background-size: contain`. It's frustrating.

Comment: You might be interested in the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute of an SVG. Then you can just make your background `100%` in both directions and the SVG should scale and cut correctly. It should also work in CSS backgrounds. Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

Comment: I see it does work really well when scaling up the viewport but when i shrink the window the height of the container gets pregressibly bigger. `preserveAspectRatio:"xMidYMid meet"` is what I tried.

Comment: Those `preserveAspectRatio` values are a bit confusing, I always need to try a couple to find what I need (they make sense but my brain won't join in) Pretty sure it would solve your issue if the block has an appropriate size. Sizing the block based on a background image isn't possible, though.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using padding, since the percentage value for padding is based off the parent element's width. Instead of using height I used `padding-block:10%` and `background-size:cover`.

```
const Background = styled.section`
  border: solid 1px red;
  background: url(${Donationsvg}) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  padding-block: 10%;
`;
```